# Unexpected result on the number of permutations with a restriction.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, integer-partitions, catalan-numbers

Let $p=(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n)$ be a weak composition of a positive integer number $n$ into $n$ non-negative integer parts and let $k_i$ be the count of the part $i$ ($i=0,1,2,\dots$) in the composition.

A permutation $\tilde p$ of $p$ is allowed if its partial sums obey the inequality:
$$
\forall m (1\le m\le n):\ s_m\equiv\sum_{j=1}^m \tilde p_j\ge m.
$$

The simple but rather unexpected result valid by numerical evidence  is that the number of allowed permutations is
$$
\frac{n!}{\displaystyle(k_0+1)!\prod_{i>0}k_i!}.\tag1
$$

This means that the number is exactly $n+1$ times less than the number of *all* permutations of the composition supplemented by an additional 0. This simplicity suggests that there should be almost obvious
explanation of the fact but I could not find it.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $n$ **"partitioned"** into $n$ parts : then the parts can just be all equal to $1$ . are you speaking  instead of [weak composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) ?

Comment: @GCab I mean a partition into **non-negative** parts, not into the positive ones. For example $(5,0,0,0,0)$ is an allowed partition of $5$.

Comment: @user Partitions of integers are not usually considered to be ordered the way your sequences are. "Composition" is a less ambiguous term.

Comment: that is not a **partition** in the standard meaning.  Is it ordered or not ? if not it is a **weak composition**

Comment: @GCab Is it ok to speak about a permutaion of a weak composition?

Comment: @user: Yes: a permutation of a weak composition is another weak composition.

Comment: in a composition the parts are not ordered, so the set of compositions of a given number includes the permutation of the parts, with the caution that the parts can be repeated ..  So definitely, make better clear (with a couple of examples) what you are actually considering

Comment: @GCab If you see how to improve the wording of the question, feel free to edit it. English is not my native language.

Comment: @GCab: In a composition the parts **are** ordered: $1+4$ and $4+1$ are distinct compositions of $5$. (It’s partitions that aren’t ordered.)

Comment: I want to say that for any given permutation of $p$ with a zero added (which we'll call $p_0$): if one considers all the $n+1$ cyclic permutations of $p_0$, exactly one of them satisfies the given inequalities. Can anyone supply a proof (or refutation)?

Comment: @GregMartin Unfortunately that doesn't work. An allowed permutation can't start with 0, whereas $k_0+1$ of the cyclic permutations will start with 0. I've tried variations on cycling to no avail.

Comment: @GregMartin That's not true. E.g. take $(1, 2, 0, 2, 0)$. Then both cyclic $(1, 2, 0, 2, 0)$ and $(2, 0, 2, 0, 1)$ will work. Also, if that were true, then we would have $ (n-1)!$ many solutions.

Comment: @user Can you elaborate on "This means that the number of allowed permutations is equal to ... with one added 0 divided by n+1.  "?

Comment: @GregMartin The claim becomes true when we append a 0, and ignore the $n+1$ equation. E.g. take $(1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0)$, then only $ (2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0)$ works. My solution sketches out the reason.

Comment: @CalvinLin What do you mean with "elaborate"? Obviously you correctly understood the sentence. If it is ambiguous please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @user The comment was made before I found my solution. In addition, I wasn't sure if you were talking about a specific permutation, or summing it up across all permutations to conclude that "Catalan numbers  $= 1/(n+1) \times { 2n \choose n}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin I was speaking about a specific weak composition of a number $n$ "merged" with an additional $0$. If you know how to express this better I would be very thankful for a corresponding edit.

Comment: Given that you're describing multiple actions at the same time, I encourage you to break it up into distinct parts. E.g. the phrasing of "equal to the number of X with one added 0 divided by n+1" was really confusing. Was the 0 divided by n+1? Are we concatenating X with 0? Are we adding 0 to X, then dividing by n+1?  $\quad$

At the very least, adding commas would have been helpful. If you see my solution, I decided to break that up into distinct steps with explanations.

Comment: @CalvinLin Please check my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given any weak composition $p = (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$, append an extra $0$ to it, and consider the rearrangement $ p' = (p_1' p_2', \ldots , p_n', p_{n+1}' )$.
There are $\frac{ (n+1)! } { (k_0 + 1) ! \prod k_i ! } $ such rearrangements.
We can naturally pair them up into groups of size $n+1$, obtained by cyclically permuting the indices.

For such a rearrangement, we associate it to the "up and right path" of:

- Start at $(0,0)$,
- Go up $p'_1$, go right 1.
- Go up $p'_2$, go right 1.
- $\ldots $
- Go up $p'_n$, go right 1.
- Go up $p'_{n+1}$, which brings us to $(n, n)$.

We use the bijection as described in [the third proof of Catalan's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Third_proof). The following  is a section of the writeup which contains the necessary information, though I encourage you to read the full details on Wikipedia for more context.

> The **exceedance** of the  path is defined to be the number of vertical edges which lie above the diagonal.
>
> Given a path whose exceedance is not 0, then we may apply the following algorithm to construct a new path whose exceedance is one less than the one we started with.
>
> - Starting from the bottom left, follow the path until it first travels above the diagonal.
> - Continue to follow the path until it touches the diagonal again. Denote by X the first such edge that is reached.
> - Swap the portion of the path occurring before X with the portion occurring after X.
>
> The algorithm will cause the exceedance to decrease by one, for any path that we feed it, because the first vertical step starting on the diagonal <s>(at the point marked with a black dot)</s> is the unique vertical edge that under the operation passes from above the diagonal to below it; all other vertical edges stay on the same side of the diagonal.
>
> It is also not difficult to see that this process is reversible: given any path P whose exceedance is less than n, there is exactly one path which yields P when the algorithm is applied to it.

Using this algorithm, we conclude that the $n+1$ cyclic permutations each have a unique exceedance. Since this exceedance ranges from 0 to $n$, and there are $n+1$ of them, hence it's exactly the integers from 0 to $n$ (inclusive).

Here's the bijection for the case of $n = 3$.
The rows are cyclic permutations of $ (3,0,0,0), (2, 1, 0, 0), (1, 2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0)$.
The columns have exceedance $3, 2, 1, 0$.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/65/Catalan_number_algorithm_table.png))</sub>

Now, verify that an allowed permutation has an associated staircase diagram that stays on or above the line $ y = x$, hence has exceedence exactly $n$.

Finally, the number of allowed permutations is (the desired):
$$ \frac{1}{n+1} \times \frac{ (n+1)! } { (k_0 + 1) ! \prod k_i ! } = \frac{ (n)! } { (k_0 + 1) ! \prod k_i ! } $$

In the case of $n=3$, this corresponds to the first column, and the allowed permutations are $(3, 0, 0), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)$.

---

Corollary: The total number of allowed permutations is the Catalan number $C_n$.

Comment: An excellent and obviously correct idea! Can you elaborate on the claim that the map of a path obtained by the "third proof" construction is a cyclic permutation of the map of the initial path? By the map I assume the arrangement $ p = (p_1,p_2, \ldots , p_n, p_{n+1})$ introduced in your answer.

Comment: @user More accurately, a cyclic permutation of $p'$. The change made by the algorithm is just "swap the portion of the path occurring before X with the portion occurring after X", which is a cyclic permutation of $ p'$. (yes, details have to be checked.)