# Looking for analytical proof that this function given as a power series is constant.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

Answering a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3986731) I came across the following function ($t$ is a positive integer), defined for $0\le x\le 1$ as:
$$
P_t(x)=x^t\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n+1}\binom{t(n+1)}n\left[(1-x)x^{t-1}\right]^n.
$$

Is there an analytical way to prove that $P_t(x)$ is a continuous function on $x\in(0,1)$ and:

1. $P_t(x)=1$ for all $x:\ 0\le 1-x\le\frac1t$,
2. $P_t(x)<1$ for all $x:\ \frac1t< 1-x\le1$.

I proved this for trivial cases $t=1,2$ but did not find a way to deal with general $t$.

The behavior of the function for $t=1,2,3,4$ is demonstrated below:

[image]

Comment: One trivial observation is that $P_t(1)=1$ for all $t\geq 1$, since in that case the sum collapses to the $n=0$ term. (This is especially trivial in the original context: If you always win, the game never ends.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's analytic about $x=1$. Doing the substitution $x \mapsto 1-x$, collecting coefficients, and using the binomial series quickly reduces it to the following identity. I've used $\tau := t-1$.

**Thm:** For all $k, \tau \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{k-n}}{n+1} \binom{(n+1)(\tau+1)}{n} \binom{n\tau}{k-n}  = \binom{\tau+k}{k}. \label{*}\tag{*}$$

**Proof:** This identity was new to me, though @Semiclassical pointed me in the right direction in the comments! As Knuth says in his note on [Convolution Polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207221.pdf), p.5, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x+t(n-k)}{n-k} \binom{y+tk}{k} \frac{y}{y+tk} = \binom{x+y+tn}{n}. \label{**}\tag{**}$$
Let $t \mapsto \tau+1$, $n\mapsto k$, $k\mapsto n$, $y\mapsto \tau+1$, and $x\mapsto (\tau+k)-(\tau+1)(k+1)$ in $\eqref{**}$ and applying $\binom{\tau n}{k - n} (-1)^{k-n} = \binom{-\tau n + k - n - 1}{k - n}$ gives $\eqref{*}$. $\Box$

**Remark:** Knuth notes that $\eqref{**}$ goes back to Rothe in 1793 (!) in the guise of what is apparently known as the [Rothe--Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity). Knuth references [Gould and Kaucky](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980066800303) who provide further references and discussion as well. A short elementary proof is provided by [Chu](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1n24/pdf).

Comment: This also has the smell of some proof by counting, though there's of course a big difference between saying that and proving it.

Comment: One other notable point: As best I can tell, the terms on the left-hand side are always integers. That definitely seems combinatorial, e.g., some kind of inclusion-exclusion argument.

Comment: I tried the calculus of finite differences, the Pascal recurrence, and Vandermonde convolution to no avail, and I had no ideas on an inclusion-exclusion approach. It seems oddly resistant to direct attacks. Surely it or something equivalent to it is in somebody's paper or reference work, but I haven't found it.

Comment: You might try looking at Knuth's paper on [Convolution polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207221). That has the scent of this, but I don't know enough to verify further.

Comment: It was in there!

Comment: Excellent! If I understood correctly you reduce the problem to the simple sum $\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{\tau+k}k x^k=\frac1{(1-x)^{\tau+1}}$. Why does not it work for $x>\frac1t$?

Comment: @user The reduction uses that formula, but the identity (**) is quite a lot harder. As for the radius of convergence, I started with $x \mapsto 1-x$ followed by a series expansion about $x=0$, which is only valid in a neighborhood of 0. The radius of convergence works out to be $1/t$.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. I'd wondered if the [Rothe-Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity) would be an avenue, but 1) I didn't see how to account for the alternating series, and 2) I didn't see the utility of Knuth's simplification of such.

Comment: I see now. Could you write the full solution for future references? I also extended my question to cover the behavior of the function on the whole domain $[0,1] $. I would appreciate if you comment also on this issue.

Comment: I've updated the discussion of the key identity. I may or may not get to writing up the other details, and I am curious about the expansion about $x=0$ of your original function--@user, you're certainly welcome to edit the post with them if you wish!

Answer (score 2):

*comment*
Interesting.  I tried $n=7$ in Maple, and the result was
$$
P_7(x) = {x}^{7}
{\mbox{$_7$F$_6$}\left(1,{\frac{8}{7}},{\frac{9}{7}},{\frac{10}{7}},{\frac{11}{7}},{\frac{12}{7}},{\frac{13}{7}};\,\frac43,\frac32,\frac53,{\frac{11}{6}},2,{\frac{13}{6}};\,-{\frac { \left( -823543+823543\,x \right) {x}^{6}}{46656}}\right)}
$$
That graph does, indeed, look like yours.  Why?

Comment: This seems to be possibly simplified. I think that I found the general pattern but I do not know what to do with it ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

This contribution is a development of the answer given by Joshua and aims mainly at clarification of the remaining questions. It will be assumed that $t>1$.

As already indicated in the mentioned answer it is advantageous to replace $x$ with $1-x$ and consider the function
$$
P_t(x)=(1-x)^tF_t\left(z_t(x)\right)\tag1
$$
with
$$
F_t(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n+1}\binom{t(n+1)}n z^n.\tag2
$$
and
$$
z_t(x)=x(1-x)^{t-1}.\tag3
$$

First of all let us investigate the behavior of $z_t(x)$. While $x$ runs from $0$ to $1$ the function first monotonically increases from $0$ to $z^*_t$ and then monotonically decreases back to $0$, the maximum $z^*_t$ being attained at $x=\frac1t$. Thus any value $z:\ 0\le z<z^*_t$ is attained exactly by two values of $x$: $0\le x_1<\frac1t$ and $\frac1t<x_2\le 1$. On the domain $x\in[0,\frac1t]$ the function can be inverted and we shall refer to the inverse function (defined on the domain $z\in[0,z^*_t]$) as $z^{-1}_t(z)$.

For convenience we introduce the function
$$
X_t(x)=z^{-1}_t(z_t(x)).
$$
Observe:
$$
X_t(x)\begin{cases}
=x,& 0\le x\le \frac1t;\\
<x,& \frac1t<x\le 1.
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

The next figure shows the function $z_t(x)$ and indicates the action of the function $X_t(x)$ for $x>\frac1t$.

[image]

Let us now investigate the convergence of the series $F_t(z)$ in the neighborhood of $z=0$.

The ratio of the series coefficients reads:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}&=\frac n{n+1}\frac{(nt+t)!}{n!(nt+t-n)!}\frac{(n-1)!(nt-n+1)!}{(nt)!}z\\
&=\frac 1{n+1}\frac{(nt+t)!}{(nt)!}\frac{(n(t-1)+1)!}{(n(t-1)+t)!}z\\
&=\frac {nt+1}{n+1}\frac{nt+2}{n(t-1)+2}\cdot\frac{nt+3}{n(t-1)+3}\cdots\frac{nt+t}{n(t-1)+t}
z,\tag5
\end{align}$$
so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=t\left(\frac t{t-1}\right)^{t-1}z.
$$

Thus the series $F_t(z)$ converges if
$$
|z|<\tilde z_t=\frac1t\left(1-\frac1t\right)^{t-1}.\tag6
$$
Observe that $\tilde z_t$ is precisely the maximum value $z^*_t$ of the function $z_t(x)$.

Substituting in $(5)$ $z=z^*_t$ and expanding in powers of $\frac1n$ one obtains
$$
\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=1-\frac32\frac1n
+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right),
$$
so that by [Raabe test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe%27s_test):
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}-1\right)=\frac32>1
$$
the series converges also for $z=z^*_t$.

After the absolute convergence is established one can demonstrate applying the Rothe-Hagen identity:
$$\forall x: 0\le x\le\frac1t:\ F_t\left(z_t(x)\right)=\frac1{(1-x)^t}.\tag7
$$
The proof is given in the answer of Joshua and will be repeated in the appendix below.

Using $(7)$ one obtains:
$$\begin{align}
P_t(x)&=(1-x)^tF_t(z_t(x))\\
&=\frac{(1-x)^t}{(1-X_t(x))^t}
\underbrace{\left[(1-X_t(x))^t F_t(z_t(X_t(x)))\right]}_{=1}\\
&=\left(\frac{1-x}{1-X_t(x)}\right)^t.\tag8
\end{align}$$

In view of the property $(4)$ one concludes that indeed:
$$
P_t(x)\begin{cases}
=1,& 0\le x\le \frac1t;\\
<1,& \frac1t<x\le 1.
\end{cases}\tag9
$$

---

**Appendix: Proof $P_t(x)=1$ for $x\le\frac1t$.**

Let us consider a more general function:
$$
P_{Tt}(x)=(1-x)^TF_{Tt}(z_t(x)),\quad\text{with}\quad F_{Tt}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac T{T+nt}\binom{T+nt}nz^n,\tag{A1}
$$
and $z_t(x)$ being defined by $(3)$. The previously considered case corresponds to $T=t$.

The convergence analysis can be proceeded exactly as in $(5)-(6)$. For $x<\frac1t$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
P_{Tt}(x)&=(1-x)^T\sum_{n\ge0} \frac T{T+nt}\binom{T+nt}n x^n(1-x)^{nt-n}\\
&=(1-x)^T\sum_{n\ge0} \frac T{T+nt}\binom{T+nt}n x^n\sum_{m\ge0}\binom{nt-n}m (-x)^m\tag{A2}\\
&=(1-x)^T\sum_{k\ge0} \left[\sum_{n\ge0}\frac T{T+nt}\binom{T+nt}n(-1)^{k-n}\binom{nt-n}{k-n}\right]x^k\tag{A3}\\
&=(1-x)^T\sum_{k\ge0} \left[\sum_{n\ge0}\frac T{T+nt}\binom{T+nt}n\binom{k-1-nt}{k-n}\right]x^k\tag{A4}\\
&=(1-x)^T\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{T+k-1}kx^k\tag{A5}\\
&=(1-x)^T\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{-T}k(-x)^k\tag{A6}\\
&=(1-x)^T(1-x)^{-T}=1\tag{A7},\\
\end{align}$$
where in $(\text A4)$ and $(\text A6)$ we applied $\binom{-a}k=(-1)^k\binom{a+k-1}k$, and in $(\text A5)$ - the [Rothe–Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity):
$$
\sum_{k\ge0}\frac a{a+bk}\binom{a+bk}k\binom{c-bk}{n-k}=\binom{a+c}n,
$$
valid for any complex numbers $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for comments.*

Assuming that $t$ is a positive integer, there is no problem to get explicit formulae up to $t=3$.

For $t \geq 4$ appear hypergeometric function and the result write
$$P_t(x)=\frac x {1-x} \big[Q_t(x)-1\big]$$
$$Q_4(x)=\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{4^4}{3^3} (1-x) x^3\right)$$
$$Q_5(x)=\,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{5^5}{4^4} (1-x) x^4\right)$$
$$Q_6(x)=\,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6};\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5};\frac{6^6} {5^5}(1-x) x^5\right)$$
$$Q_7(x)=\,
   _6F_5\left(\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{6}{7};\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6};\frac{7^7}{6^6} (1-x) x^6\right)$$

For $x=x_*=1-\frac 1t$, $Q_t(x_*)=\frac t{t-1}$ and then $P_t(x_*)=1$ as you observed.